# python3 IDLE3 Flask Socket IO error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-idle, flask-socketio

yeah so i was using idle, browsing stack overflow, when i came upon this code snippet. Its a basic python flask Socket Io app that does no system calls what soEver. But, for some reason, when i run it IDLE just does a shell restart. when i added a debugging print statement: `print(3)`, this is the traceback I got 
`* Restarting with stat--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):Traceback (most recent call last):`
 and nothing after the colen.
the following is the code i was trying to run:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template                                    
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit                                      
print(3)
app = Flask(__name__)                                                           

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'                                            
socketio = SocketIO(app)                                                        

@socketio.on('connect')                                                          
def connect():                                                                 
    emit('message', {'hello': "Hello"})                                         

@app.route('/')                                                                
def index():                                                                   
    return render_template('index.html')                                        

socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

PS: it runs in terminal correctly

Comment: IDLE runs your code in a subprocess of its GUI process, so the internal environment is slightly different than when run in a terminal.  Although rare, this can result in problems for code that depends on internal details.  The IDLE Shell restart almost certainly means that the separate process crashed.  If you start idle in the terminal with `python -m idlelib` you *might* get either better behavior, because this alters certain internal details, or a better error message.

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT**

Turns out, that it was due to installing `gevent`

Idk why gevent breaks idle, but i  installed it because the socketio
output recommended to do so.

well, now you know